# Adding a event listener for a click search button as well as the enter button

Tags: javascript, onclicklistener, event-listener

I am trying to add an event listener to a search button. I already have the event listener for the enter button but want people to be able to click on the search button as well. For example, on a mobile device they will have to do this. Could someone please help me? Any help would be massively appreciated. Thanks

```
enquiryRef.addEventListener('keypress', checkIfEnter);

function checkIfEnter(event){
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    getResults(enquiryRef.value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the event listener to the search button too.

```
searchBtn.addEventListener('keypress', checkIfEnter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add more than one event listener to an element, but of course exactly what you want to do on a click will be different from what you want to do on the user keying in Enter as there will be no  Enter key to check. So create another function, say userClicked, which just calls the getResults with the value like when a user keys Enter.

```
enquiryRef.addEventListener('keypress', checkIfEnter);

function checkIfEnter(event){
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    getResults(enquiryRef.value);
  }
}

enquiryRef.addEventListener('click', userClicked);

function userClicked(event){
    getResults(enquiryRef.value);
}
```

Depending on your use case you may or may not want to stopPropagation of the click.